Calculating Pressure Drop from Water Pipe Discharging to Atmosphere
I have an application at work where I am draining a water tank. The outlet valve is a flush mount, and I know the Cv value from manufacturer website. I can calculate the pressure drop through this valve and piping. The piping goes to an atmospheric drain which is 5 ft lower than the tank bottom. Will there be a discharge pressure drop at the very end of the drain pipe that I must take into account? The end goal is I want to calculate the free-drain flow rate at various tank water levels. A derivation/proof that there is in fact a pressure drop there would be especially helpful.

Any pipe, orifice or valve generates a pressure loss due to friction.

I don't think that the pipe end should generate any significant local pressure loss when there is discharge of water into atmospheric air.

gauge pressure at the exit is zero.  Every water hose works this way, and has friction head loss.  Delta p is fluid height pressure minus zero.

Do you have a nozzle at the end of the drain pipe? Are you discharging into Air or liquid?

@SamiSafarini there is no nozzle. Discharging to air.

Using Bernoulli equation:
$$P_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_1^2 + \rho gh = P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_2^2 $$

$P_1$ and $ P_2 $ are the pressures at the surface and the orifice, respectively.
$v_1=0 \ $ The water velocity at the surface, can be ignored if the tank's surface is much bigger than the orifice.
$v_2 $ is the velocity of water at the orifice$\ =\sqrt{2gh}.\ $ We ignore the valve friction, in this case, it's irrelevant.

Pressure drop at the orifice
$$P_1 + \rho gh +0= P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 $$
We set $P_1=P_2= 1atm$
$$\Delta P = P_1 - P_2 = \rho gh - \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$$
Substituting
$$v = \sqrt{2gh}\\  \rightarrow \quad \Delta P = \rho gh - \frac{1}{2} \rho (2gh) = \rho gh - \rho gh = 0$$
There is no pressure loss at the discharge. This roundabout was just to repeat the obvious: when the discharge and tank are both exposed to the atmosphere, they are at the same pressure!
